# Matlab: Eliminating freak values in dataset

Tags: matlab, filter

I am searching for a method to eliminate freak values out of given dataset. For example:

[image: Dataset to be filtered]

All these peaks should be eliminated. I've tried different filters like `medfilt`, but the peaks are still there. I've also tried a lowpass filter, but it didn't work either. I am a beginner in filtering signals, so I probably did it wrong.

You can download data sets for the [x array here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11129082/x-data.mat.html) and [y array here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11129083/y-data.mat.html).

I could also imagine a loop to compare the values next to each other, but I am sure there has to be a built-in function?

Here is the result using `medfilt1(input,15)`:

[image: filtered signal]

The peaks are vanishing, but the then I get these ugly steps, which I don't want.

Comment: A simple method is to diff your data and see where the change in value exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJsU.jpg) is what I associated to when I read "freak values in dataset".

Comment: Haha Andras, actually I just translated the german word and I got "freak values" =D excaza, so you mean like to loop trough the data, and check for a certain diff and eliminate it? I had this Idea too, but I thought there might be a build in function...

Comment: Do you want to replace the "freak" values with an interpolated value from nearby samples or do you just want to remove the "freak" values?

Comment: I think an interpolation would be better, thus I don't need to adjust my x-vector

Comment: One of the reasons that you're having trouble is the your x data, `v_Rolle1`, looks corrupted as well and isn't monotonically increasing. Zoom in on your first plot. You can try sorting the data: `[X,idx] = sort(v_Rolle1);` `plot(X,P1(idx));`.

Comment: I didn't notice this. I will try it out.

Answer (score 7):

just use median filter! `medfilt1(data,3)` will do if this is a 1 pixel "cosmic" spike. If the peaks remain, increase the window size to 5 or more...

**EDIT:**
so this is how op's data looks like:

[image]
So we see that the data is not exactly uniform or ordered, and there are a lot of data points in the spikes unlike what one first understand from the question (guys please plot your data correctly!)  The question is now, is the data in the spikes or on in the baseline?

Comment: I tried the medfilt1 function again, but I need atleast 15 to get the most peaks away, but then instead of just eliminate the peaks, I get steps in the graph...I will add the graph in the question...

Comment: better yet, give a link to the data itself in .mat file

Comment: Just use window size at least twice greater, that the width of your pick

Comment: I tried, but then my graph looks like a staircase... as to see in the second graph

Comment: It's a bit more complicated as the x data isn't monotonic.

Comment: I just noticed the x-axis data... hmmmm

Comment: First I am wondering, why your plot looks so different (much more noise) than mine.Is this related to the change of the axes? I am also just uses the plot() command. I was hoping for a smoother graph at the end...

Comment: I just didnt see the x data, I thought there's only 1 mat file... I'll edit an answer... I understand you still  want to get rid of the spikes? or is your data actually the spikes ?

Comment: Oooooh this figure changes everything! You can't get rid of the spikes @deSteini: those *are* your data! The fact that you have some non-peak lines below just means that from spike to spike the plot command draws *something*. You could've as well chosen the maxima of each peak. Try plotting it without lines, just markers. What is your signal then? I believe you should filter each peak somehow, by assigning a single value per peak. Clustering your `x` data can give you the peaks, and you can use mean/median/min/max/whatever to get a single representative value at the given `x`.

Comment: so is the data in the spikes or not?

Comment: now I understand! I assume the data is in the spikes, as it should be a measurement of the max engine power over the velocity.. Sorry guys for causing you that trouble ..

Comment: @deSteini that's still a valid problem, but it needs a very different approach. I'd use some peak-wise averaging of the values, although the standard deviation should be informative along with that data.

Comment: Yes I just think the same. First excluding the data of the baseline (cause I think it's wrong) and mean the preak values. So I would get one value for each peak...

Comment: well at least you have a way to get the baseline (a.k.a staircase) now after `medfilt1`  :-)